# How to get university level Mathematics education on my own?

Tags: education, learning

As far as Mathematics go, I have a highschool level education. I wonder how I could learn more about Mathematics to be on the level of those who had Mathematics level education at a university. Is there a way I could learn it on my own? If yes, how?

Comment: I'm guessing "go to a university" is not a real option here, so a better (probably) idea: get into several universities' programs of undergrad mathematics and read there what the syllabus of each subject is. Many of these subjects have a site of their own there and you can then read a little about the books, objectives and etc. each course has. Now get those books and begin (it'll be very hard, probably). Another option: go to a nearby university and ask people there.

Comment: Great question. I'm in your same situation. I cannot afford university at present, but I intend to enroll after acquiring some basic knowledge in the main areas of mathematics. I've started with calculus, linear algebra,... and I'm currently exploring the wonderful world of the theory of functions and functional analysis. Good luck, enjoy the beauty of the Queen of Sciences and hear the suggestions of the more experienced people here!

Comment: 50 years ago, I would have said: Read Bourbaki

Comment: Today, I would say: Read Amann/Escher.

Answer (score 6):

You could try self study with some classic texts. (Personally, I'd start with Spivak's Calculus.)

But inevitably, you will want someone to answer your questions and there's nothing like the cold shower of having your first hundred or thousand proofs/solutions read by a very critical eye.

So you might also consider hiring a tutor to do those two things.